# How flexible is DataBinding in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

> How flexible is DataBinding in WPF? I
>   am new to WPF and would like to have a
>   clear idea. Can I Bind a string
>   variable with a Slider value? Does it
>   always have to be a control?
>
> Is it at all possible to bind a string
>   value with a Slider control so that it
>   updates in real time? How far up the
>   Logical tree does the update travel or
>   do we have to reissue all the commands
>   to use this new value?

That was my hurried question earlier. I am posting a detailed problem.

What I am trying to do is, I have an application with multiple user-controls. These user controls are grid-views and contain controls (TextBox, Button) and sections of my application UI. I used this approach to split my main XAML file across multiple files and it works for me till now. Now, I have a Slider in one user control and want to bind a String variable in another user control. The string variable is read-only so there is no use for two-way binding.

I hope that makes my question clear. In my code, I am trying to update the variable zoomFactor in:

```
URLQuery.Append("&zoom=" + zoomFactor + "&size=600x500&format=jpg&sensor=false");
```

with a Slider control. For those who could spot that, yes, it is the Google Static Maps API and yes, I am trying to zoom into the map with a slider.

Comment: I don't know if you resolved this yet but how are you in any way supposed to change a read-only property? Why is it read-only? You want to change it - then don't make it read-only!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You generally can do such things by using `IValueConverter`.

When you create a proper converter you can specify to use it for the binding in the XAML.

For the "real time" part, as far as you implement INotifyPropertyChanged properly in your DataContext object, modifying the variable will be reflected on the UI, applying all the value converter you decided.Lets'have an example using a slider as you said:

```
<Window x:Class="Example.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Example"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        >
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:HMLConverter x:Key="hiloConverter"></local:HMLConverter>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Slider Value="{Binding MyValue, Converter={StaticResource hiloConverter}}"  Maximum="100" Minimum="0"/>
</Window>
```

I created a little converter, called HMLConverter, than maps a string variable to the value 0-50-100 for the respective "lo","med",ang "hi" strings. The converter is declared as a static resource, and used in the binding. Converter code looks like:

```
namespace Example
{
    public class HMLConverter:IValueConverter
    {
        #region IValueConverter Members

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            string val = value.ToString();
            int ret = 0;
            switch (val.ToLower())
            {
                case "hi":
                    ret = 100;
                    break;
                case "lo":
                    ret = 0;
                    break;
                case "med":
                    ret=50;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new NotSupportedException("Value " + val + " is not supported");
            }
            return ret;

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

As you probably guess, I wrote it only in one direction, so the binding does not works in both way, but I'm sure you got the whole part.

Comment: Thanks Felice for going through the trouble of writing that code. However, what I wanted was the exact opposite. The value in the slider will change, and the value of the String will change accordingly. The Slider is in one user-control (say userCtrl_child) and this further resides in another user control (say userCtrl_parent) and there is another C# class file, say inpValidator.cs. All of these are in the same Namespace. Now, I want to update a string value (say inputSlider in inpValidator.cs) by changing the slider value (slider.Value in the userCtrl_Child), through DataBinding.

Comment: Is it advisable to set the datacontext of a parent container to this String value s that I would not have to travel all the way through the Application.

Comment: @r3st0r3 just implement the convert back that I left unimplemented.

Answer (score 1):

how flexible? so flexible it hasn't failed once for me.

you can do pretty much anything with WPF's bindings. You can bind double values to strings by using Converters. you can get a value from multiple bindings (MultiBinding). You don't have to worry about change propagation.

As this sounds like a decision for/against the use of WPF depending on how capable binding is, worry not! you can do anything!

If you have a specific problem, please post a specific question.

Comment: It does fail me a lot though.. Take a look at my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798447/is-mvvm-pointless/4671141#4671141

Comment: Can't bind to a method. :P But I agree it's pretty flexible so long as you know what you're doing.

Comment: No Markus, this is not a decision against using WPF. I am enjoying WPF till now and I love this new system of separating the UI layer with a really powerful markup language. I am adding an additional (non-critical) feature to my project and wanted to do it the correct way, through DataBinding because I am using WPF.

Answer (score 1):

Databinding in WPF is much better than databinding in Winforms, if that's what you're asking about?

Not only are there more options for easy conversion, as suggested by Markus, there are fewer edge cases to worry about, it is more likely to Just Work.

Comment: I am not asking about that. We can have better DataBinding in WPF through a brand new DependencyProperty system. INotify aso works from .NET 2.0.

Comment: Yes, and you can have Object Oriented code in C. Doesn't mean that the default frameworks and languages support it.

Answer (score 1):

Once you learn the limitations, WPF's binding system is pretty flexible.

Any type can be bound to any other type. If the types don't have an obvious conversion then you can use an `IValueConverter` to convert from one type to another.

The limitations I've found so far are:

- Cannot bind to a method. Bindings can only happen between properties.
- You can only bind to `DependencyProperties` on controls. Most properties are `DependencyProperties`, but occasionally they are not, which can be frustrating.
- Things can become complex when an elements `DataContext` is set by WPF and a child element wants access to the original `DataContext`. For example, in a `ListBox` each item's `DataContext` is set to the item in the `ListBox`. So if you want the `DataContext` of the `ListBox` you have to jump through some hoops.
- Another binding issue comes from items that are not part of the visual tree, like `ContextMenus`. Similar to items in a `ListBox` you have to jump through a few hoops to get them to work properly.

Most people implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to allow WPF to watch for changes to their bound objects. But you can also use `DependencyProperties` so long as your object inherits from `DependencyObject`.

Comment: That is a very helpful list. It is going into my WPF quick-reference book. Thanks.